# Teamcity start very slow

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I install a Teamcity server in my DigitalOcean Droplet, the machine is 2 core and 4G memory.

I have check the log, But it seem like every thing is right. I put the Teamcity behind my nignx web server.

The problem is sometime Teamcity start may take half an hour, and I can't get any information for Teamcity

I only know the jvm is running, if I visit the url through ningx I only get 502

Comment: Check out [related documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Reporting+Issues#ReportingIssues-Slowness%2CHangingsandLowPerformance) and 
[report to TeamCity team](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/Feedback).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had the same problem and was able to solve it with help from the JetBrains staff. During startup, teamcity needs access to `/dev/random` as a RNG and the default `/dev/random` does not hold enough entropy to fulfill that need. This blocks the startup process, until enough entropy has been gathered again.

Solution is to install the [havaged](http://www.issihosts.com/haveged/) daemon to fill the entropy enough.

See also: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-41035 for the original discussion.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at server logs, that would give you an idea on where most of the time is spent.